# Swift - No data displayed in TableView after Retrieving it from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, tableview, codable

I am trying to get the data I have saved and then load it into the TableView. Currently, if I am saving the object for the first time, the data gets encoded, saved, decoded, read and displayed correctly. However, if the key already exists and I am adding to the existing data, nothing gets displayed in the TableView.

This is currently how I am saving it in the first view controller:

```
let userEntry = UserEntries(date: String(todayDate), questions: [UserEntries.Question(question: q1Text, answer: q1Answer), UserEntries.Question(question: q2Text, answer: q2Answer)])

    var allEntries : [UserEntries] = []
    if doesKeyExist(key: "allEntries") == true {
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "allEntries"),
            let userEntries = try? jsonDecoder.decode(UserEntries.self, from: data) {
            allEntries = [userEntries]
        }

        allEntries.insert(userEntry, at: 0)

        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let value = try? jsonEncoder.encode(allEntries) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "allEntries")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    } else {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let value = try? jsonEncoder.encode(userEntry) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "allEntries")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }

    let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabViewController") as! UITabBarController
    present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is how I'm displaying it in the TableView

```
var TableData : [UserEntries] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "allEntries"),
        let userEntries = try? jsonDecoder.decode(UserEntries.self, from: data) {
        print(userEntries.date)
        TableData = [userEntries]
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "entryCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row].date
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row].questions[0].answer

    return cell
}
```

I have a feeling that this is a logic error, in getting/displaying the data in the TableView, but am unsure of what exactly it is/how to fix it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does `doesKeyExist`? Not related but why do you write the `JSONEncoder` code twice? Just move the `else` line up after `allEntries.insert(` and delete the second occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your `doesKeyExists` function does but you can improve your data manipulation by this way:

```
    let userEntry = UserEntries(date: String(todayDate), questions: [UserEntries.Question(question: q1Text, answer: q1Answer), UserEntries.Question(question: q2Text, answer: q2Answer)])

    var allEntries : [UserEntries] = []

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "allEntries"),
         let userEntries = try? jsonDecoder.decode([UserEntries].self, from: data) {
        allEntries = userEntries
    }

    allEntries.insert(userEntry, at: 0)

    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let value = try? jsonEncoder.encode(allEntries) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "allEntries")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabViewController") as! UITabBarController
    present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the problem with your controller is that you are saving only one entry to `UserDefaults`. Try to change your code to

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "allEntries"),
    let userEntries = try? jsonDecoder.decode([UserEntries].self, from: data) {
    print(userEntries)
    TableData = userEntries
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Just by the way, doesKeyExist is to check whether the key exists in UserDefaults